# resize automatically iframe height

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i include a iframe in master page and i want to resize iframe height according to its contents inside.

when ever iframe content increase iframe height should be increase.

```
<div id="div_NotificationOuter" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px; right: 15px;
            padding: 5px; background-color: White; background-image: url('../images/content_fixed_downup.png');
            background-repeat: no-repeat; min-height: 130px; text-align: left; display: block;
            border: 1px solid gray; width: 280px; overflow: hidden;">

    <asp:ImageButton ID="img1b" runat="server" ImageUrl="../images/close.png" 
                Style="margin-right: 2px;float:right;" OnClientClick="Hide_NotifyPopUp()" />
```

ALERTS

Your browser does not support iframes.

and iframe page is

```
<div id="iframe_content">
        <div style="overflow: auto;font-weight:bold " >
            <label id="lblNotifyMessage" runat="server" style="margin-left:15px;">

            </label>
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 14px;margin-left:15px;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblCount_Followups" runat="server" Text=""
                Style="margin: 2px"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblCount_Workflow" runat="server" Text="" 
                Style="margin: 2px"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblCount_Inbox" runat="server" Text=""
                Style="margin: 2px"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="111115000">
            </asp:Timer>

            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Notification Message"
                Style="margin: 2px"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Notification Message"
                Style="margin: 2px"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Notification Message"
                Style="margin: 2px"></asp:Label><br />


            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Notification Message"
                Style="margin: 2px"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Notification Message"
                Style="margin: 2px"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Notification Message"
                Style="margin: 2px"></asp:Label><br />


            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Notification Message"
                Style="margin: 2px"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Notification Message"
                Style="margin: 2px"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Notification Message"
                Style="margin: 2px"></asp:Label><br />

        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have jQuery and you know when the content height changes you can resize it with this:

`$('#iframe').height($('#iframe_content').height());`

Comment: whery i shuld use this function

Answer (score 0):

You have to call a function on the parent page from the iframe to do this.

On parent page, create a similar function like this

```
function resizeIframe(var) {
    $("iframeid").height(var);
}
```

Now, from inside the iframe call the following snippet

```
$(window).load(function() { 
// ^ Once everything load. You can change this any event suitable
    parent.resizeIframe($(window).outerHeight());
});
```